How to Choose Good Values for minimum, maximum, and preferred in CAFrameRateRange?
I'm working with a CADisplayLink in iOS to synchronize my rendering with the screen refresh rate. On devices running iOS 15 or later, CADisplayLink allows us to specify a preferredFrameRateRange using CAFrameRateRange(minimum:maximum:preferred:).
I'm trying to understand how to choose the best values for minimum, maximum, and preferred based on different use cases. Here's the setup I'm working with:
let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(render))
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    displayLink.preferredFrameRateRange = CAFrameRateRange(minimum: 30, maximum: 120, preferred: 60)
} else {
    displayLink.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60
}
displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .default)

How should I decide on the values for minimum, maximum, and preferred?

For example, what values are suitable for apps that need smooth animations or high performance?

Is there any guidance on how these values affect ProMotion displays (like the iPhone 15 Pro Max) that dynamically adjust refresh rates?

Are there any specific trade-offs or best practices to consider for adaptive frame rates or energy efficiency?



I'm sure you've read this article, and I doubt any better recommendation can be provided, except test your app in various phones / conditions and adjust if you find any issues specifically related to frame rate...

@timbretimbre yes i read it, but testing the app in various conditions is really unpracticable, their is too much possible variation :(

good testing has strategies to cope with variability. For example: 1- identify a few most likely "profiles" of your users (what are they doing, which device they are likely yo use) and test with these profiles; 2 - select relevant dimensions and test edges (e.g. for display rate best supported hardware, worst supported hardware); 3 - make sure you have enough feedback baked into your app, so information collected during testing and on beta release gives you understanding what real users experienced
